# Javascript Hide/shown Toggle Didn't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to Make a Javascript Toggle Such that when i click on any of below divNO buttons only that div shown all other Hide. But It didn't work:

```js
function toggle(show,hide) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    
    document.getElementById(id).style.display= 'none';
  
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick="toggle('show','hide')">div1</a>
<a href='#' onclick="toggle('show','hide')">div2</a>
<a href='#' onclick="toggle('show','hide')">div3</a>
<a href='#' onclick="toggle('show','hide')">div4</a>
<a href='#' onclick="toggle('show','hide')">div5</a>
<div class='div1' >first div</div>
<div id='id' class='div2' style='display:none'>second div</div>
<div id='id' class='div3' style='display:none'>third div</div>
<div class='id' style='display:none'>fourth div</div>
<div class='id' style='display:none'>fifth div</div>
```

Comment: Some debugging advice, look at the error console. You'll see an error in trying to set a property on null. This should tell you that your `getElementById` method has failed. If you look closer you will see that you haven't set a value to `id`. You also have duplicate id values on your html elements, they must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your markup little bit and javascript function as well. See below:

HTML Part:

```
<a href='#' onclick="toggle('div1')">div1</a>
<a href='#' onclick="toggle('div2')">div2</a>
<a href='#' onclick="toggle('div3')">div3</a>
<a href='#' onclick="toggle('div4')">div4</a>
<a href='#' onclick="toggle('div5')">div5</a>
<div id='div1' class="div">first div</div>
<div id='div2' class="div" style='display:none'>second div</div>
<div id='div3' class="div" style='display:none'>third div</div>
<div id='div4' class="div" style='display:none'>fourth div</div>
<div id='div5' class="div" style='display:none'>fifth div</div>
```

And JavaScript Part:

```
function toggle(id) {
    var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
        divsToHide[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: just note that this will hide ALL divs in the page and then only show the one with the target id. Not a good solution IMO. My solution targets only the divs with the specific class to hide them and then apply the active class thoe display the selected item.

Comment: Not all div it hiding only but which div have class "div" this is not div tag. I just showed his a way how the code work he can re-format as he want, he can give class name "something-else" instead of "div".

Comment: Ha Ha - sorry  @Hanif - I missed that it was the class .div not the element <div> ... fair point :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you....

```js
$("a").click(function(){
   var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
    $(myelement).toggle();
    $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
    
  });
```

```css
div.toggle{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#div1"> DIV 1</a> 
   <a href="#div2"> DIV 2</a>
   
<div class ="toggle" id="div1">div1</div>

<div class ="toggle" id="div2">div2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data attribute to set an index of the link clicked and tehn use jquery to hide / show the links.

UPDATE - it is always better to add / remove classes with rather than directly affecting the css of the element. In that vein - I have amened my solution to add / remove the 'active' class on the divs - and this is whattoggles the disply state.

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('.sampleDivs').removeClass('active');
  $('#div' + id).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.sampleDivs {display:none}

.sampleDivs.active {display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' data-id='1'>div1</a>
<a href='#' data-id='2'>div2</a>
<a href='#' data-id='3'>div3</a>
<a href='#' data-id='4'>div4</a>
<a href='#' data-id='5'>div5</a>



<div id ='div1' class='sampleDivs active'>first div</div>
<div id ='div2' class='sampleDivs'>second div</div>
<div id ='div3' class='sampleDivs'>third div</div>
<div id ='div4' class='sampleDivs'>fourth div</div>
<div id ='div5' class='sampleDivs'>fifth div</div>
```

Comment: As there is an id on your divs I would still use the `href` attribute of your `a` tags instead of a data attribute. It is more semantic as you are effectively linking to an element on the existing page.

Answer (score 0):

First up there may be a CSS only solution for you, using `:target` . The issue with this is displaying a div by default.

```css
.sampleDivs {display:none;}

.sampleDivs:target{display:block;}
```

```html
<a href='#div1'>div1</a>
<a href='#div2'>div2</a>
<a href='#div3'>div3</a>
<a href='#div4'>div4</a>
<a href='#div5'>div5</a>


<div id ='div1' class='sampleDivs'>first div</div>
<div id ='div2' class='sampleDivs'>second div</div>
<div id ='div3' class='sampleDivs'>third div</div>
<div id ='div4' class='sampleDivs'>fourth div</div>
<div id ='div5' class='sampleDivs'>fifth div</div>
```

As the question is tagged with jQuery, here is a semantic jQuery alternative that leverages the `href` attribut.

```js
$(".divSelector").click(function(){
    $(".sampleDivs").hide();
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();       
    return false; 
});
```

```css
.sampleDivs {
  display: none;
}

.sampleDivs.default {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#div1' class="divSelector">div1</a>
<a href='#div2' class="divSelector">div2</a>
<a href='#div3' class="divSelector">div3</a>
<a href='#div4' class="divSelector">div4</a>
<a href='#div5' class="divSelector">div5</a>


<div id='div1' class='sampleDivs default'>first div</div>
<div id='div2' class='sampleDivs'>second div</div>
<div id='div3' class='sampleDivs'>third div</div>
<div id='div4' class='sampleDivs'>fourth div</div>
<div id='div5' class='sampleDivs'>fifth div</div>
```

Comment: I really Like Your CSS Only Solution